# Using <ItemTemplate> with Checkbox and Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I want to be able to show the Label next to the manually inserted item "All Profiles", right now it only shows the checkbox at the top but I am not sure how to pass the text to the  label.

Thanks

Comment: I tried <%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Name") %>, still shows the checkbox and no label :( ..only the first one (the manually added one) the other ones have a checkbox and the label ok..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try databinding again after inserting "All profiles"-item.
If that doesnt work, try something like this:

```
var values = myDbConnection.GetValues();
var listOfValues = values.Select(x => new ListItem(x.Name, x.Value)).ToList(); // something like that
listOfValues.Add(new ListItem("All Profiles"));

myCombo.DataSource = listOfValues;
myCombo.DataBind();
```

Comment: I tried it and it now removed the checkbox and shows the list as if the manual item was never added. :(

Comment: I've updated the code, but you need to adjust it to fit your result coming from the myDbConnection.GetValues(). The point of it is to first create a collection of ListItems and then manually add the "All profiles" before making the databind call.

Comment: I added the values.select but it appears the classes from where it is being pulled does not allow Selects.. I appreaciate all the help.. I guess I will get stock here. :( I am new at c# so..

Comment: You must add System.Linq in a using statement for it to work.

Comment: Yeah the problem is the that myDBConnection thing is comming from a bunch of classes so it is giving an error that those libraries do not have a select blah blah . It has the linq there

Comment: You can also skip using linq and instead add what you get from myDbConnection.GetValues(), with the "All Profiles"-item to a regular List. Then you can databind that collection to myCombo.

Comment: Actually that function is returning a TList<> of some type. So how would I handle it?

Comment: Read up on generics and you should be able to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like that?

```
<telerik:radcombobox id="myCombo" emptymessage="All Types" runat="server" width="200px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">       
    <ItemTemplate>         
        <div onclick="StopPropagation(event)">           
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk1" onclick="onCheckBoxClick(this)"/>             
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProfile" AssociatedControlID="chk1"><%# Eval("Name") %></asp:Label>               
        </div>              
    </ItemTemplate>
        <Items>                
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Name="Hello"></telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
    </Items>
</telerik:radcombobox>
```

Comment: @user710502 What did not work means? This is valid answer and should work. AppendDataBoundItems=True will append all data-bound ListItems to the DropDownList, leaving those you add manually as the first.

Comment: Oh i did not see the AppendDataBoundItems = true.. I am going to try now.

Comment: Tried again, this time it added my list three times and three checkboxes with no label.

Answer (score 1):

Telerik recommends to rebind added items in the **DataBound** event handler like the following

```
ddlCombobox.Items[0].DataBind()
```

Check the following links for similar issue on Telerik site

http://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/view-ticket.aspx?threadid=327434

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-insert-default-item-when-databinding.html